# React Native - Navigating from a native iOS screen to a React Native Screen

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, react-native

I have recently added iOS native code (in swift) to an existing React Native project.
I am able to display my custom UIViewController after pressing on a button on React Native screen, which is nice.

I would now like to display a React Native screen on top of that UIViewController (also after pressing a button), and then be able to navigate back.

I tried using react navigation, but since my native screen is on top, the navigation is hidden behind my UIViewController.
I read the React Native documentation, however I am still not sure on how to approach this issue with navigation.

Is there a way to do so? if so, what would be the best approach?

Thank you in advance!